# GestureOverlayView not working perfectly on layout

Tags: android, gesture

I am currently working on a project which include Gestures. It's work perfectly but i want put padding or margin on gesture but not layout change which i want. How to put padding or margin in gestures?

my xml code:

```
<FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.50"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/bg_alpha"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" >
            </ImageView>

            <android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
                android:id="@+id/draw_on_gesture"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/a_draw" 
                android:eventsInterceptionEnabled="true">
            </android.gesture.GestureOverlayView>

        </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Can you say clearly please! Are you talking about GestureBuilder?

Comment: GestureOverlayView used in xml layout. layout not set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/hello"
/>
<android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
android:id="@+id/gestures"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gestureStrokeType="multiple"
android:eventsInterceptionEnabled="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Also refer to [this link](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Implementing_Android_Custom_Gesture_and_Pinch_Recognition), it may help also.